# Nginx RTMP didn't accept HEVC h265 input format

Tags: ffmpeg, h265, hevc

I'm trying to created live event broadcast on my VPS server , to make the audience able watch my broadcast I use `Nginx RTMP` that's produce link at this format `http://192.168.1.5:8080/hls/live.m3u8` this is my ffmpeg command

`ffmpeg  -re -i <input> -s 634x360 -vb 110k  -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -ab 38k  -ar 44100 -f mpegts  rtmp://localhost/hls/live`

command output

```
frame= 1465 fps= 25 q=-0.0 size= 1231kB time=00:00:58.56 bitrate= 172.2kbits/s speed=0.999x
```

Nginx config file

```
server {
listen      8080;
server_name  localhost;
 location /hls 
   {
     types 
       {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
       }
      root /tmp;
      add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
  }
```

so the encoding runs on mealtime but when I try to access `live.m3u8` url I got `nginx 404 Not Found` error message like Nginx didn't generate .m3u file at all .

==update

Alright I found workaround solution to generate `.m3u8` file directly from ffmpeg using this command

```
  ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0 -c:v libx265 -vb 300k -c:a aac -ab 38k -ar 44100 -preset veryfast -f ssegment -segment_list /var/www/vhl/live.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 -segment_wrap 30 /var/www/vhl/live%01d.ts
```

I was able to play it via VLC for which is good for now
to gain more performance e.g you have huge number of audience mount your output folder `/var/www/vhl/` as `tmpfs`

Comment: HLS does not accept HEVC.

Comment: HLS does support HEVC using an mp4 container. RTMP does not support HEVC.

Comment: Alright I found workaround solution to generate .m3u8 file directly from `ffmpeg` using this command `ffmpeg -i <input> -map 0 -c:v libx265 -vb 300k  -c:a aac -ab 38k -ar 44100  -preset veryfast -f ssegment -segment_list /var/www/dmain/live.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 -segment_wrap 30 /var/www/dmain/live%01d.ts` I was able to play it via VLC for which is good for now .

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write FLV.

Answer (score 1):

Update, as of March 2023, RTMP has added support for HEVC. Refer to [Enhanced RTMP](http://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v6/doc/hevc). Therefore, both RTMP and FLV standards now support HEVC.

Support status for related open-source projects:

- OBS 29 supports RTMP HEVC. Refer to [Enable AV1, HEVC via RTMP to YouTube](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/pull/8522).
- FFmpeg's patch for Enhanced RTMP support has been submitted and is under review.
- mpegts.js 1.7.3 supports HTTP-FLV HEVC. Refer to [FLV with HEVC support](https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js/issues/64).
- SRS media server 6.0 supports RTMP HTTP-FLV HEVC. Refer to [H265: Support HEVC in RTMP/SRT/HLS/WebRTC/DASH/GB28181](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/465).

To test RTMP HEVC, you can use OBS, patched FFmpeg, and SRS. First, start SRS:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -p 1935:1935 -p 8080:8080 ossrs/srs:6 \
  ./objs/srs -c conf/hevc.flv.conf
```

Download OBS 29+ from [here](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/releases), select the HEVC codec, or use FFmpeg 6.0 to publish RTMP HEVC stream:

```bash
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i doc/source.flv -acodec copy -vcodec libx265 \
  -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/livestream
```

> Note: Build or patch FFmpeg 4/5/6+ with HEVC over RTMP, please see this [post](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v6/doc/hevc#ffmpeg-tools).

Now, you are able to play HTTP-FLV or HLS with HEVC codec:

- HTTP-FLV(by H5): [http://localhost:8080/live/livestream.flv](http://localhost:8080/players/srs_player.html?autostart=true)
- HLS(by VLC or fflay): `http://localhost:8080/live/livestream.m3u8`

Keep in mind that FFmpeg 6.0 does not support HEVC over RTMP until the following commit
[637c761b](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/637c761be1bf9c3e1f0f347c5c3a390d7c32b282):

```
commit 637c761be1bf9c3e1f0f347c5c3a390d7c32b282
Author: Steven Liu <liuqi05@kuaishou.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 28 09:59:24 2023 +0800

    avformat/rtmpproto: support enhanced rtmp
    
    add option named rtmp_enhanced_codec,
    it would support hvc1,av01,vp09 now,
    the fourcc is using Array of strings.
    
    Signed-off-by: Steven Liu <lq@chinaffmpeg.org>
```

For details, please refer to [SRS HEVC Usage](http://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v6/doc/hevc#usage).